# Can't change editText input from string to float

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
package com.example.tipcalculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.text.toFloat as kotlinTextToFloat


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        val tenPerTip: Button =       findViewById(R.id.tenPerTipButton)
        val fifteenPerTip: Button =   findViewById(R.id.fifteenPerTipButton)
        val twentyPerTip: Button =    findViewById(R.id.twentyPerTipButton)
        val customTip: Button =       findViewById(R.id.customTipSubmit)
        val sumRaw: EditText =        findViewById(R.id.billEnter)
        val tipOnlyResult: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tipOnlyResult)
        val totalResult: TextView =   findViewById(R.id.totalResult)
        val sumString = sumRaw.toString()
        val sumInput = sumString.toInt()

        tenPerTip.setOnClickListener{
            val sumTotal = sumInput * 1.1
            val tipOnly = sumInput * 0.1
            tipOnlyResult.text = tipOnly.toString()
            totalResult.text = sumTotal.toString()
        }
        fifteenPerTip.setOnClickListener{

        }
        twentyPerTip.setOnClickListener{

        }
        customTip.setOnClickListener{

        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to switch the EditText input to a string and from there to a float so that I can do calculations on it. On the line with `val sumInput = sumString.toInt()` the code breaks. It will compile, but when I try to run an emulator it casts error codes about the `toInt` declaration. The code is using toInt in this because I was trying to see if the emulator would like that. Also whenever I declare that `toInt` it highlights in a light yellow italic font, which I haven't seen before.

Comment: `I was trying to see if the emulator would like that`, so what did the emulator say?

Comment: it still won't run the app. It casts an error on run `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)`

Comment: May be because you haven't entered a number in `R.id.billEnter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Edited your code.
Changes to the code is explained with the comments below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        val tenPerTip: Button = findViewById(R.id.tenPerTipButton)
        val fifteenPerTip: Button = findViewById(R.id.fifteenPerTipButton)
        val twentyPerTip: Button = findViewById(R.id.twentyPerTipButton)
        val customTip: Button = findViewById(R.id.customTipSubmit)
        val sumRaw: EditText = findViewById(R.id.billEnter)
        val tipOnlyResult: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tipOnlyResult)
        val totalResult: TextView = findViewById(R.id.totalResult)

        /** if you put sumString and sumInput here, what happens is when your app
         *  is created and the onCreate method is called sumString is initialized
         *  here without using .text, i.e., sumRaw.text command what happens is sumString
         *  will be initialized with sumRaw value (i guess maybe sumRaw id) and you will 
         *  get error.
         *  Also, this is only called once when all the other variable are initialized.
         *  If you want to use it outside use a TextWatcher and change the variable as
         *  soon as it is updated in the EditText.
         *  A work-around would be initializing this value inside OnClickListener, what
         *  happens here is whenever you click tenPerTip Button sumString is Initialized
         *  with current values in sumRaw EditText.
         *  
         *  Do use .text else it will give errors.
         */
        

        tenPerTip.setOnClickListener {

            val sumString = sumRaw.text.toString()
            
            // what happens here is sumString is converted to Double if it has valid pattern
            // else it will return null
            // And then the elvis operator will check for null. If its null, it will not
            // not proceed further and will get out the listener. 
            
            val sumInput = sumString.toDoubleOrNull() ?: return@setOnClickListener

            val sumTotal = sumInput * 1.1
            val tipOnly = sumInput * 0.1
            tipOnlyResult.text = tipOnly.toString()
            totalResult.text = sumTotal.toString()
        }
        fifteenPerTip.setOnClickListener {

        }
        twentyPerTip.setOnClickListener {

        }
        customTip.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use logcat and check what results you are getting, if you use:
1. sumString in onCreate without .text
2. sumString in onCreate with .text
3. sumString in OnClickListener without .text
4. sumString in OnClickListener with .text
I believe you will get same answers in case of 1 and 3 but not in case of 2 and 4, if there is something in EditText View

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think the that when you write `val sumString = sumRaw.toString()`, it gives you the text entered in `R.id.billEnter` which is not correct. to get text from an `EditText` you have to use `text` property. As for your code it can be fixed as

```
tenPerTip.setOnClickListener{
    val sumString = sumRaw.text.toString()
    val sumInput = sumString.toInt()
    val sumTotal = sumInput * 1.1
    val tipOnly = sumInput * 0.1
    tipOnlyResult.text = tipOnly.toString()
    totalResult.text = sumTotal.toString()
}
```

Comment: K. I used that code but the `toInt` piece is still casting several errors when the app tries to launch. I can't paste the whole error message here but heres a snippet `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)`

Comment: This code won't run until the button is clicked. Did you forget to move these variable declarations inside the click listener? If they declared before the listener, they will be initialized at app start-up, when the EditText is still empty, so the text in the EditText is not an Int and will crash when you try to parse it as an Int. It needs to be inside the button listener so it is evaluated when the button is pressed. You should probably replace `toInt()` with `toIntOrNull() ?: 0` so it won't crash if the user types in something that isn't an Int.